# pandas time series plot show the last timestamp in xticks

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I am plotting a data frame with time series information in it. When I plot the dataframe, sometimes the end timestamp show in the graph, while sometimes it is missing. I am using the following code to get a hold on how many x-ticks are shown().

```
# set x ticks to start from 00 to end
start_date=df.index[0].date()
end_t = df.index[-1]
width = end_t - start_date
ticks_list = [pd.tslib.Timestamp(start_date + idx*(width/10)) for idx in range(0,11)]
if end_t not in ticks_list:
  ticks_list.append(end_t)

...

ax.set_xticks(ticks_list)
```

I am specifically adding the end time if it is not in ticks list, but still sometimes it is absent from the graph. How do we force it to show up as the last end of x ticks? The beginning shows up fine as 00:00:00.

Comment: sometimes the last timestamp is not shown in the generated plot. How do we force it to show up as the last end of x ticks? The beginning shows up fine as 00:00:00.

Comment: Are you doing the plotting within pandas or matplotlib?

Comment: I use pandas df.plot(ax=ax,....)

Comment: Please provide a small subset of the `DataFrame` you are trying to plot, as well as the code you use to produce the plot, not just the snippet above. What version of Python and pandas are you running? Also, is it acceptable for you to do the plotting in matplotlib, as that is way more flexible than plotting with pandas?

Comment: Not totally following your problem, but it seems that you had the same problem as as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17079587/2107677