# Pandas plotting two graphs on one scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a line graph that I am highligting at end with a marker(shown as large red diamond here).

I am using two two pandas plot commands to create it.   Problem is that I get unexpected results.   depending on the length of the data and whether I put the plot for the red diamond first or second I get different results.   There does not seem to be a pattern that I can discern. The Correct / Expected result shown below

[image: Correct / Expected result]

sometimes i get:

[image]

and most of the time with big data sets I get the following warning:

*/Users/xxxxx/.virtualenvs/test2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:2542: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left==right results
in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
left=15727, right=15727
  + 'left=%s, right=%s') % (left, right))*

The Warning only shows 1st time it happens.   Obviously pandas does not like support the plotting of 2 different series with different x scales on the same axis?

Can try code below to generate the graphs, can play around by passing, Series or Dataframes for plot can also reverse the order of the plotting of the red diamond.   Can also change the number of data points.   One error that I could not recreate here is with the red diamond in middle and blue line only going of to left.

Code:

```
plot_with_series = False
reverse_order = False
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20101115', periods=800)
df =  pd.DataFrame(randn(len(dates)), index = dates, columns = ['A'])
ds = pd.Series(randn(len(dates)), index = dates)
clf()
if plot_with_series:
    if reverse_order: ds.plot()
    ds.tail(1).plot(style='rD', markersize=20)
    if not reverse_order: ds.plot()
else:
    if reverse_order: df.plot(legend=False)
    df.A.tail(1).plot(style='rD', markersize=20,legend=False)
    if not reverse_order: df.plot(legend=False)
```

The errors/warnings happen from both within IPython or from running the as script from command line.  Also constant across 2 latest versions of pandas.  Any ideas or obvious problems?

Comment: For me it creates two figures, the first (is a combination of the first three, or maybe the first two are overwritten), the second if from the last plot. Weird. May be worth posting this as a [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).

Comment: yes, in Ipython it sometimes create two figures.  If run as a script it alway merges them (Got bunch of these going into a latex document).  Need a clf() before next one to reset.  Not sure if this is bug or if I am misusing pandas' interface with matplotlib

Comment: At the first run, you are clearing a figure which doesn't exist yet. I think actively creating the figure and axes yourself gives you better readable code. So before plotting do: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` for example, and then always pass the axes to pandas with `ax=ax`. That gives you full control/insight on what gets plotted on which axes and figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think pandas by default creates a new plot instead of using the 'active' plot. Capturing the axes and passing it to the next plotting command works fine for me, and is the way to go if you want to reuse your axes.

Change the last two lines in your example to:

```
ax = df.A.tail(1).plot(style='rD', markersize=20,legend=False)
if not reverse_order: df.plot(legend=False, ax=ax)
```

Difference is that the axes returned by matplotlib (via pandas) is captured, and passed again with `ax=ax`. Its also more conform the preferred OO-style for using matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with previous answer, but also adding another way. Adapted from the official pandas documentation on plotting http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html
I just adjusted the second column of the DataFrame to be only the last point on a padded nan column.

```
df['B'] = np.nan 
df['B'][-1] = df.A[-1]   # Just 1 datapoint
plt.figure()
with pd.plot_params.use('x_compat', True):
    df.A.plot(color='b')
    df.B.plot(style='rD', markersize=12)
```